# Kendo UI Grid, Add columns and columns sum values

Tags: javascript, datasource, kendo-grid

I'm working with the Kendo Grid tool. 
I have a data source which contains values ​​of an object and in this object exists another one.  Is like two array, one inside the another one.

```
$("#PedidoConsolidadoGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: mData,
        schema: {
            model: { // define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                id: "CodigoArticulo",
                fields: {
                    //CodigoPedido: { editable: false },
                    CodigoArticulo: { editable: false },
                    FechaPedido: { editable: false },
                    CantidadExistencias: { editable: false },
                    DescripcionArticulo: { editable: false },
                    CantidadConsolidar: {
                        editable: true, 
                        type: "number", 
                        validation: { required: true, min: 0, max: 9999 },
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 11
    },
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: true,
    editable: {
        mode: "inline", // mode can be incell/inline/popup with Q1 '12 Beta Release of Kendo UI
        confirmation: false // the confirmation message for destroy command
    }, // enable editing
    selectable: "single",
    pageable: {
        numeric: true,
        previousNext: true,
        refresh: true,
        buttonCount: 5,
        messages: {
            display: "Mostrando {0}-{1} de {2}",
            empty: "No hay datos para mostrar",
            page: "Enter page",
            of: "de {0}",
            itemsPerPage: "Pedidos por página",
            first: "Primera página",
            last: "Última página",
            next: "Siguiente",
            previous: "Anterior",
            refresh: "Refrescar"
        }
     },
     columns: [
         //{ field: "CodigoPedido", title: "Código del Pedido", width: "150px" },
         { field: "CodigoArticulo", title: mData[0].CodigoArticulo , width: "150px" },
         { field: "DescripcionArticulo", title: "Articulo", width: "200px" },
         { field: "FechaPedido", title: "Fecha Pedido", width: "150px", template: '#= kendo.toString( toDate(FechaPedido), "dd/MM/yyyy" ) #' },
         { field: "CantidadConsolidar", title: "Total Pedido", width: "120px", },
         { field: "CantidadExistencias", title: "Total Existencia", width: "120px" },
         { command: "edit", text: "Editar"}
     ],
});
```

How should I create the columns, for data that are in the array into another array?
and how to sum columns and display the total in another column of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check into calculated properties, in this case CantidadConsolidar might be a calculated field.

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
data: [
  { first: "John", last: "Doe" }, 
  { first: "Jane", last: "Doe" }
],
schema: {
  model: {
    // Calculated field
    fullName: function() {
      return this.get("first") + " " + this.get("last");
    }
    fields:{
        ...
    },
  }
}
```

});

Also, check [DataSource Aggregates](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-aggregate) to display a sum of the values un a certain column of your grid.